# Select unique values of one column with single non unique value of another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following table, from which I have to fetch resultant rows:

### **SAMPLE TABLE**

```
id  |  Course
----+----------------------
39  |   B.Sc.-IT-6
40  |   B.Sc.-CS/DCS-2
41  |   B.Sc.-CS-3
42  |   B.Sc.-CS-4
43  |   B.Sc.-CS-5
44  |   B.Sc.-CS-6
45  |   MBA-3
46  |   MBA-3
47  |   MBA-3
48  |   MBA-3
49  |   MBA-3
50  |   MBA-3
51  |   MBA-3
52  |   MBA-3
53  |   MBA-4
54  |   MBA-4
55  |   MBA-4
56  |   MBA-4
57  |   MBA-4
58  |   MBA-4
59  |   BA-1
60  |   BA-2
```

I want to retrieve duplicate values displayed only once with the id of first value like

### **EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
id  |   course
----+---------------------
39  |   B.Sc.-IT-6
40  |   B.Sc.-CS/DCS-2
41  |   B.Sc.-CS-3
42  |   B.Sc.-CS-4
43  |   B.Sc.-CS-5
44  |   B.Sc.-CS-6
45  |   MBA-3
53  |   MBA-4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

**QUERY**

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS 'ID',column_name 
FROM test 
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY id;
```

**[FIND SQLFIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48724/3)**